# Convert data type for nested elements in list

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
list1 = [{'time_period': '202004130000', 'count': 16859}, 
{'time_period': '202004140000', 'count': 21557}]
```

The value for `time_period` is a string but I need to change it to a date. How can do this?

I tried the following but it is not correct:

```
for x in list1:
    x['time_period'] = x['time_period'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: string format is not correct - p = datetime.strptime("202004130000","%Y%m%d%H%M"), yearmonthdayhoursminutes - %y%m%d%H%M. lower case m is month; UPPER case M is minutes.

Comment: Can you please edit the title, it's really misleading? *"Fornat to convert these datetimes?"* would be more accurate. It doesn't matter that it's in a nested list of dicts.

Comment: If I wanted to exclude the minutes and seconds, could I do the following: datetime.strptime(x['time_period'][0:8], '%Y-%m-%d') ?

Comment: `strptime` doesn't format the date; it reads the date in a specified format and outputs a datetime object. `strftime` formats a datetime object into a specified string format.

Answer (score 1):

Your string appears to have format `%Y%m%d%H%M`. 
So if you want a datetime object (date), you would use

```
from datetime import datetime
x['time_period']=datetime.strptime(x['time_period'],'%Y%m%d%H%M')
```

Otherwise, if you're saying you want it formatted differently, you would use

```
x['time_period']=datetime.strptime(x['time_period'],'%Y%m%d%H%M').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

which would replace the input format with the one you specified.

This is a good reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: Is there a way to eliminate or hide the hours and mins? I tried using slicing the string but that didn't work. When I took the data into Excel, the hour and time?

Comment: The second method eliminates the hours and mins with `strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` after converting the original string to a `datetime` object with `strptime(x,'%Y%m%d%H%M)`, which does need to know the format of the input string x, including hours and mins as `%Y%m%d%H%M`.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!